# Array or Object?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, schema

I am using MongoDB and designing a database.

There is a list of `itemCode`. It won't change, but some new one will be added at some point. The total number of `itemCode` will never be over 100.

Each item has some properties.

I have two ways in my mind, one way is using **array**, another way is using **object**:

```
{
    items: [
        {itemCode:"aaa", property1:100, property2:100},
        {itemCode:"bbb", property1:100, property2:100}
    ]
}

{
    items: {
        aaa: {property1:100, property2:100},
        bbb: {property1:100, property2:100}
    }
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: This is highly opinionated question, but it's you, who know the purpose of data and how will you use it. If you are going to perform some manipulations on itemCode, then go for storing them as object. It's seems more natural to me as itemCodes do have their properties.

Comment: @Saleem I don't have so much experience on database, thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while using, I tried both. But I finally goes with this:

```
{
    items: [
        {itemCode:"aaa", property1:100, property2:100},
        {itemCode:"bbb", property1:100, property2:100}
    ]
}
```

At first I used "aaa" and "bbb" as key names, but it is hard to maintain.
For example it is hard to know how many items using that way.

But using array, it is easy to get length of an array.